# vaapi Surface to openGl texture

Tags: opengl, glew, libav, egl, vaapi

I got video frames decoded with vaapi/ffmpeg into a VASurface. Now I want to render them using an OpenGL texture. I was able to load the frames into software (with `vaDeriveImage` und `vaMapBuffer`) and update a texture with the received data. But that was really slow and that is not my goal here. Then I found EGL used in a few other repos.

So I found [this repo](https://github.com/intel/ffvademo), which does render the frames entirely with EGL as far as I see. This is not what I want. I need it in texture for later use.

Then I came across [fmor's demo program](https://github.com/fmor/demo_ffmpeg_vaapi_gl). This looks really like magic to me. There are like 2 steps on init and then he can use the texture with no problems.

```
//in player.c before the decoding happens:
egl_image = egl_create_image_from_va( &surface, player->video_va_display, player->video_cc->width, player->video_cc->height );
    if( egl_image == EGL_NO_IMAGE )
        goto LBL_FAILED;

    glGenTextures( 1, &player->video_texture );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, player->video_texture );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES( GL_TEXTURE_2D, egl_image  );

//in util.c:
EGLImage egl_create_image_from_va(VASurfaceID* _va_surface, VADisplay va_display, int width, int height)
{
    EGLImage egl_image;
    VASurfaceID va_surface;
    VASurfaceAttrib va_surface_attrib;
    VADRMPRIMESurfaceDescriptor va_surface_descriptor;
    int r;

    egl_image = EGL_NO_IMAGE;
    va_surface = VA_INVALID_SURFACE;

    va_surface_attrib.type = VASurfaceAttribPixelFormat;
    va_surface_attrib.flags = VA_SURFACE_ATTRIB_SETTABLE;
    va_surface_attrib.value.type = VAGenericValueTypeInteger;
    va_surface_attrib.value.value.i = VA_FOURCC_RGBA;

    r = vaCreateSurfaces( va_display, VA_RT_FORMAT_RGB32, width, height, &va_surface, 1, &va_surface_attrib, 1 );
    if( r != VA_STATUS_SUCCESS )
        goto LBL_FAILED;

    r = vaExportSurfaceHandle( va_display, va_surface, VA_SURFACE_ATTRIB_MEM_TYPE_DRM_PRIME_2, VA_EXPORT_SURFACE_READ_ONLY, &va_surface_descriptor );
    if( r != 0 )
        goto LBL_FAILED;

    EGLAttrib egl_img_attributes[] = {
        EGL_LINUX_DRM_FOURCC_EXT, va_surface_descriptor.layers[0].drm_format,
        EGL_WIDTH, va_surface_descriptor.width,
        EGL_HEIGHT, va_surface_descriptor.height,
        EGL_DMA_BUF_PLANE0_FD_EXT, va_surface_descriptor.objects[va_surface_descriptor.layers[0].object_index[0]].fd,
        EGL_DMA_BUF_PLANE0_OFFSET_EXT, va_surface_descriptor.layers[0].offset[0],
        EGL_DMA_BUF_PLANE0_PITCH_EXT, va_surface_descriptor.layers[0].pitch[0],
        EGL_NONE
    };
    egl_image = eglCreateImage( eglGetCurrentDisplay(), EGL_NO_CONTEXT, EGL_LINUX_DMA_BUF_EXT, NULL, egl_img_attributes );
    if( egl_image == EGL_NO_IMAGE )
        goto LBL_FAILED;


    *_va_surface = va_surface;
    return egl_image;
LBL_FAILED:
    if( va_surface != VA_INVALID_SURFACE )
        vaDestroySurfaces( va_display, &va_surface, 1 );
    return EGL_NO_IMAGE;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is happening here? And how I can reproduce this without using glew?

My hardest guess is that with the EGL_LINUX_DMA_BUF_EXT parameter for the eglImage creation there is some direct memory accessing ongoing. Is vaapi rendering right into the OpenGL texture here?

Also here is `vaExportSurfaceHandle` used and I don't really get what this is doing.

**Edit:** I read through a lot of EGL related posts now. I think I understand a bit more now. But when I looked at [fmor's demo program](https://github.com/fmor/demo_ffmpeg_vaapi_gl) again I got confused. There are several calls of `eglGetCurrentDisplay()` but I can't find where this Display is set, so I can reproduce that. Could it be, that glew is doing something behind the scenes or am I missing something else?

Even `eglInitialze()` is never called once.

When I try to instantiate an EGLDisplay on my own with `eglGetDisplay(native_display)`, like it was done in ffvademo, what do I put in for the native_display? In ffvademo there got X11 Display or a DRM Display (?) inserted. Both are as far as I know used to render to the screen, or not? Also I think inserting the vaapi Display would be not the right thing here.
I could really use some help here guys...

Comment: So, what is your main question? EGL things? Or, mechanisms on VA-API?

Comment: It is the combination of both that is making me trouble. I got to a point where I almost had it working. But at the moment I'm stuck with an Egl allocation Error that I can't find a solution for. I can provide the code thats bothering tomorrow if you want. But i guess that would rather be another question...   Also every Information about EGL or Vaapi with an extra insight could be helpful.

Comment: I can't find any clues on the EGL allocation error in your post. Is the error a different new one than the error discussed in your post? And is the error related with the EGLDisplay things you mentioned in your post? Anyway, I'd like to hear your problems on the EGL allocation error.

Comment: Yea this post has nothing to do with my current problem anymore. I figured a lot out by myself so far. I will make a new question later today and link it here. Gonna mark this post as answered.

Comment: Forgot about that yesterday... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73303299/what-is-causing-this-egl-surface-allocation-error) is the new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. GLFW is doing all of the stuff needed. Gonna read through that code to find my answers I guess.